# phpmyadmin stuck with Query error

Tags: phpmyadmin

i can log into phpmyadmin as 'root' and access all tables. When I log in as 'user and execute a query 'SELECT * from visitors' it comes up with an error message  ( from a previous query that failed)

"right syntax to use near 'ANDDATE>'2015-06-01' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1"

I can access the table as user from command line , so its a phpmyadmin problem 
stuff that doesnt work 
ive cleared cookies
as root,
 pma_history is empty 
pma_bookmark is empty 
delete entries in pma_recent

and idea where the previous query  is stored , so that i can delete ( or alter )  it  ?

Answer (score 1):

found it  ( ubuntu 14.04 FWIW )

> /# grep -r 'ANDDATE' /var
>   Binary file /var/lib/php5/sess_fmkkbn6b68uhej1ggk3vnncd26h2stru
>   matches
>   Binary file /var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin/pma_table_uiprefs.MYD matches

deleting the entry from pma_table_ui-prefs  solved the problem

Comment: Worked like a sharm!

Comment: What exactly did you do?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and can't seem to find much solutions online.

After looking at the solution proposed by thread starter, I realize the solution is to go to your phpmyadmin database, go under the pma_table_uiprefs table, look for a record that contains the query that is throwing error, and delete that record.

Took me more than an hour to figure this out!